# Error while installing Third party module in kivy/python-for-android

Tags: android, python, kivy

i went to distribute.sh in python-for-android and then type then i type this command "./distribute.sh -m "kivy nmap" where nmap is thired party module for python but i am receiving this error ...

```html
Call postbuild_python
Call postbuild_sdl
Call postbuild_pygame
Call postbuild_pyjnius
Call postbuild_android
Call postbuild_kivy
Run pymodules install
We want to install: nmap
Check if /usr/local/bin/virtualenv is present
Check if a virtual environment already exists
Installing virtualenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Create a requirement file for pure-python modules
Install pure-python modules via pip in venv
/root/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
DEPRECATION: --download-cache has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Pip now automatically uses and configures its cache.
Collecting nmap (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
/root/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nmap (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for nmap (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

please solve this someone

Answer (score 0):

```
Check if virtualenv is present
Tool virtualenv is missing
```

Install virtualenv.

Edit: Since you edited your question:

```
No matching distribution found for nmap (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

There is no module named nmap on pypi (and therefore installable with pip). If your module isn't installable this way, you can't just put it in the requirements line. If this is the case, copy the module to your app dir and it will be included with the app.